# Dataframe Split Text into new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe awith the following column `MENU_HINT` and im looking to make a new column by picking out the third word:

```
MENU_HINT
AUS / Cant (AUS) 
AUS / Darw (AUS)
AUS / YarV (AUS)
AUS / Goul (AUS)
```

My code is the following:

```
splittext = str(dfresults['MENU_HINT'])
dfresults['City'] = splittext.split()[3]
```

Which Gives Me:

```
MENU_HINT                City
AUS / Cant (AUS)         Cant
AUS / Darw (AUS)         Cant
AUS / YarV (AUS)         Cant
AUS / Goul (AUS)         Cant
```

I'm after Cant, Darw, YarV, Goul but it is fixing on the top value (Cant).

I know I'm close but cant seem to figure out the issue so any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with slicing:

```
#fourth value
dfresults['City'] = dfresults['MENU_HINT'].str.split().str[3]

#third value
dfresults['City'] = dfresults['MENU_HINT'].str.split().str[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use [`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with regex:

```
df['City'] = df['MENU_HINT'].str.extract(r'/\s(\w+)')
print(df)

           MENU_HINT  City
0  AUS / Cant (AUS)   Cant
1   AUS / Darw (AUS)  Darw
2   AUS / YarV (AUS)  YarV
3   AUS / Goul (AUS)  Goul
```

This assumes the text to match is followed by `'/'` and could be at any position.